# Javascript points calculator not working (HTML select/options + Javascript)

Tags: javascript, forms, if-statement, html-select

good afternoon from Sweden!
I have a problem with a javascript code which gives me "NaN" while trying to get it to count my points from my grades. It should check which score it is and then take what it's worth and adding that to the final score which will be alerted when pressing the button.
Javascript:

```
var biobetyg;
var bildbetyg;

function bBio() {
    var bio = document.getElementById("bio");
    var biobe = bio.options[bio.selectedIndex].value;
    if ((biobe === "-") || (biobe === "f")) {
        biobetyg = 0;
    } else if (biobe === "e") {
        biobetyg = 10;
    } else if (biobe === "d") {
        biobetyg = 12.5;
    } else if (biobe === "c") {
        biobetyg = 15;
    } else if (biobe === "b") {
        biobetyg = 17.5;
    } else if (biobe === "a") {
        biobetyg = 20;
    }
}

function bBild() {
    var bild = document.getElementById("bild");
    var bildbe = bild.options[bild.selectedIndex].value;
    if ((bildbe === "-") || (bildbe === "f")) {
        bildbetyg = 0;
    } else if (bildbe === "e") {
        bildbetyg = 10;
    } else if (bildbe === "d") {
        bildbetyg = 12.5;
    } else if (bildbe === "c") {
        bildbetyg = 15;
    } else if (bildbe === "b") {
        bildbetyg = 17.5;
    } else if (bildbe === "a") {
        bildbetyg = 20;
    }
}
var merit = bildbetyg + biobetyg;

function GetSelectedItem() {
    var strSel = "The Value is: " + merit + " and text is: ";
    alert(strSel);
}
```

HTML:

```
<form>
<h1>Bild</h1>
<h2>Välj ditt betyg i bild:</h2>
<select id="bild" onchange="bBild()">
  <option class="f" value="-">-</option>
  <option class="f" value="f">F</option>
  <option class="go" value="e" selected>E</option>
  <option class="go" value="d">D</option>  
  <option class="go" value="c">C</option>
  <option class="go" value="b">B</option>
  <option class="go" value="a">A</option>
</select>
<select id="bio" onchange="bBio()">
  <option class="f" value="-">-</option>
  <option class="f" value="f">F</option>
  <option class="go" value="e" selected>E</option>
  <option class="go" value="d">D</option>  
  <option class="go" value="c">C</option>
  <option class="go" value="b">B</option>
  <option class="go" value="a">A</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Press to Confirm" onClick="GetSelectedItem();">
</form>
```

Comment: Aside: Google 'javascript switch'

Comment: Why don't you make the values of the options be those numbers?

Answer (score 3):

As Pointy pointed out, I suggest changing your html to:

```
<form>
<h1>Bild</h1>
<h2>Välj ditt betyg i bild:</h2>
<select id="bild" onchange="bBild()">
  <option class="f" value="0">-</option>
  <option class="f" value="0">F</option>
  <option class="go" value="10" selected>E</option>
  <option class="go" value="12.5">D</option>  
  <option class="go" value="15">C</option>
  <option class="go" value="17.5">B</option>
  <option class="go" value="20">A</option>
</select>
<select id="bio" onchange="bBio()">
  <option class="f" value="0">-</option>
  <option class="f" value="0">F</option>
  <option class="go" value="10" selected>E</option>
  <option class="go" value="12.5">D</option>  
  <option class="go" value="15">C</option>
  <option class="go" value="17.5">B</option>
  <option class="go" value="20">A</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Press to Confirm" onClick="GetSelectedItem();">
</form>
```

So you can avoid the need of the `if`s (or even using `switch()` which would be a better option, and then you can change your JavaScript to (the `parseFloat()` parts are to avoid treating the values as strings, as that would only concatenate instead of adding up the numbers):

```
function bBio()
{
    var bio = document.getElementById("bio");
    var biobetyg = parseFloat(bio.options[bio.selectedIndex].value);
    return biobetyg;
    }

function bBild()
{
var bild = document.getElementById("bild");
    var bildbetyg = parseFloat(bild.options[bild.selectedIndex].value);
    return bildbetyg;

}

function GetSelectedItem()
{
    var merit = bBio() + bBild();
    var strSel = "The Value is: " + merit + " and text is: ";
    alert(strSel);
}
```

This greatly reduces your JS code and I think it's more readable... (besides actually working

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/Evkaf/)**

Comment: I don't think he wants `parseInt()` for values like "12.5".

Comment: @Pointy thanks good point I totally forgot that :) I just changed that to `parseFloat()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this line:

```
var merit = bildbetyg + biobetyg;
```

sets the variable "merit" before either of those two functions runs. It is not recomputed automatically just because the other two variables change.

Move that line of code inside the "GetSelectedItem" function and things should work much better.

You'll also need to initialize the two variables so that if the button is clicked before the values change, it still works. In fact you could have that "GetSelectedItem" function simply call the two functions itself before computing the sum.

Comment: Yes they should, but they don't. Dosen't work that way either.

Comment: @TommieMichaelLagerroos http://jsbin.com/akoniz/1 it does work, but you only perform the calculations when the select elements change.  If you click "confirm" without changing the selections, then those two variables are never set to anything.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. It's true. Thanks for the help :)